# Illegal start of expression and ';' expected error

Tags: java, syntax, compiler-errors

I am getting the illegal start of expression and `;` expected errors. I searched for similar problems but I couldn't solve my problem.

```
public int compare(Point point1, Point point2)
```

Here is the full method.

```
public static void sortByX(List<? extends Point> points)
{
    Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<Point>() );
    {
        public int compare(Point point1, Point point2)
        {
            if (point1.x < point2.x)
                return -1;
            if (point1.x > point2.x)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public static void sortByY(List<? extends Point> points)
{
    Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<Point>() );
    {
        public int compare(Point point1, Point point2)
        {
            if (point1.y < point2.y)
                return -1;
            if (point1.y > point2.y)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the full error information here?

Comment: You have a wrong "{" after Collections.sort();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `);` in the wrong place. They should appear following the anonymous implementation of `Comparator<Point>()` :

```
public static void sortByX(List<? extends Point> points)
{
    Collections.sort(points, 
        new Comparator<Point>() //); - remove these
        {
            public int compare(Point point1, Point point2)
            {
                if (point1.x < point2.x)
                    return -1;
                if (point1.x > point2.x)
                    return 1;
                return 0;
            }
        }); // add ); here
}
```

`sortByY` should be fixed similarly.